# how is the logic of neighbor values in to sub lists from integer list

Tags: flutter, dart

input =>

```
List integerList =[1,2,3,4,30,31,50,51,100];
```

expecting output =>

```
List subLists =[[1,2,3,4],[30,31],[50,51],[100]];
```

basic criteria, subtraction result of each in between values of subgroups should be less than 10

Comment: What is the point here: I need this output | expecting output. The meanings are same. Lists are same.

Comment: While it might seem obvious, what criteria are used for the grouping? I would guess the length of the number but please confirm. Also, is the provided list always in order? If not, how would [2,65,1] for example result in?

Comment: @peter, basic criteria subtraction result of each in between values of subgroup's shoudbe  lessthan 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75066050/17971818
exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

**This function return what you want:**

```
List getGroupedList(List<int> integerList) {
    List<List<int>> groupedList = [];
    while (integerList.isNotEmpty) {
      groupedList.add([integerList.first]);
      integerList.removeAt(0);
      while (integerList.isNotEmpty&&integerList.first - groupedList.last.last == 1) {///YOU CAN ALTER THIS 1 TO ANY NUMBER ACCORDING TO YOUR CRITERIA OF DIFFERENCE BETWEEN NUMBERS
        groupedList.last.add(integerList[0]);
        integerList.removeAt(0);
      }
    }
    return groupedList;
  }
```

Comment: Relax dude, it is not all about reps at the end of the day)

Answer (score -3):

OLD ANSWER

Here's an example (assuming grouping by number length):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  List integerList =[1,2,3,4,50,51,100];
  final result = integerList
      .groupListsBy((element) => element.toString().length)
      .values
      .toList();

  print(result); // prints: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [50, 51], [100]]
}
```

EDIT:

NEW ANSWER

I believe this could do what you like:

```
  List integerList = [1,2,3,4,8,30,31,50,51,100];
  final result = integerList.fold<List<List<int>>>(
      [[]],
      (previousValue, element) => previousValue.last.isEmpty ||
              (previousValue.last.last - element).abs() < 10
          ? [
              ...previousValue.take(previousValue.length - 1),
              [...previousValue.last, element]
            ]
          : [
              ...previousValue,
              [element]
            ]);

  print(result); // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 8], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100]]
```

Comment: This code groups by just length of numbers. It is not the answer!

Comment: @JakhongirAnasov how do you know this is not what OP wants? Please don't make assumptions. You are not the asker of the question

Comment: That is because, it is said neighbors in title of questions. It means they only can differ 1. I am sorry if it seems rude for you. But I still consider that your answer is just wrong.

Comment: @JakhongirAnasov I see. You are probably right. The "neighbor"  in the title probably means that. I missed that part somehow. It wasn't very clear to me

Comment: Thank you for understanding me. By the way, I provided the function, which I think that does what the asker wanted. You can check if you are interested in.

Comment: @peter, basic criteria, subtraction result of each in between values of subgroup's shoudbe  lessthan 10

Comment: @Ivo, thank you ivo, you are right for my previous question, but my question is updated now.
it's is not the answer what i want exactly.

Comment: @MuhammedSibil why is it not correct? It should work as you requested. And I see you asked a new question with almost the same, then just replace the 10 in the code with 7

Comment: input=>
List integerList=[1,2,4,11,14,15,16,16,19,30,31,50,51,100,101,105];  


i getting this one with your answer [[1, 2, 4, 11, 14, 15, 16, 16, 19], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100, 101, 105]]
i want [[1, 2, 4,], [11, 14, 15, 16, 16, 19], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100, 101, 105]]

Comment: @MuhammedSibil replace the 10 in my code with 7, in this part `(previousValue.last.last - element).abs() < 7`

Comment: yes !!. you are right @Ivo, now i got what i want exactly. thank you Ivo god bless you!
you are great programmer!

Comment: one-liner: `integerList.splitBetween((v1, V2) => (v2 - v1).abs() > 10).toList()`, more here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/splitBetween.html

Comment: @pskink you are right. I wasn't familiar with the `splitBetween` method. It's far superior to my answer

Comment: btw you could check how they manage to make it so that they don't create a new list on every iteration step, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/splitBetweenIndexed.html (the very bottom of that page)

Comment: @pskink Very nice. Questions about manipulating collections in a way are one of my favorite kinds of questions to answer and it's always nice to find one-liners or other nice concise ways to do it. It never occured to me that it might be better to produce an `Iterable` instead of a `List` but now I definitely see the benefits of it and will keep it in mind in the future