# what is the logic of neighbor values in to sub lists from list

Tags: flutter, dart

input =>

```
 List integerList=[1,2,4,11,14,15,16,16,19,30,31,50,51,100,101,105];
```

expecting output =>

```
 List sub = [[1,2,4],[11,14,15,16,16,19],[30,31],[50,51],[100,101,105]];
```

**1,2,4** 7 difference to **11,14,15,16,16,19** 11 difference to **30,31,** 19 difference to **50,51,** 49 difference to **100,101,105**

```
 basic crietirea , atleast 7 difference with the values at the time of separation of
 integerlist.
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/splitBetween.html

Comment: is the integerList random? So, what to do if the conditions are not met? next one?

Comment: Integerlist not random, it is sorted intergerList , first=> you should sort your input.

Comment: @bakboem, input should ordered manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List integerList=[1,2,4,11,14,15,16,16,19,30,31,50,51,100,101,105]; //input
//input should orderd, just sort your input otherwise you will not get expected output

var subList=integerList.splitBetween((v1, v2) => (v2 - v1).abs() > 6);
print(subList); //([1, 2, 4], [11, 14, 15, 16, 16, 19], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100, 101, 105])

//you should minus 1 from your criteria, here 7 goes to 6. or change it to:(v2 - v1).abs() >= 7
```

thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink  he is the author

Answer (score 0):

```
List integerList = [1,2,3,4,8,30,31,50,51,100];. //input should be sorted
  final result = integerList.fold<List<List<int>>>(
      [[]],
      (previousValue, element) => previousValue.last.isEmpty ||
              (previousValue.last.last - element).abs() < 10
          ? [
              ...previousValue.take(previousValue.length - 1),
              [...previousValue.last, element]
            ]
          : [
              ...previousValue,
              [element]
            ]);

  print(result); // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 8], [30, 31], [50, 51], [100]]
```

Source from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/75054991/17971818
Thanks Ivo https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514861/ivo

Comment: (previousValue.last.last - element).abs() < 10
basic criteria change asper your criteria. replace 10 to your criteria value

Comment: and what's unclear in [splitBetween](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/splitBetween.html)? Athe docs say: "Splits the elements into chunks between some elements" - you can do that in one line using that method, why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @pskink splitBetween not meet my requirements

Comment: ok, so it is `integerList.splitBetween((v1, V2) => (v2 - v1).abs() > 10).toList()`

Comment: @pskink , yes it works well! but  example, some input 1,3,4,14,16 it is not meet with same criteria,
problem 4 to 14 distance is 10 so you should down 1 from your criteria


here, (v2 - v1).abs() > 10) 10 down to 9,  (v2 - v1).abs() > 9) then it works perfect!

Comment: so change it to: `v2 - v1 >= 10` (since your data is sorted)

Comment: @pskink yes, it works exaact! , thank you! you are great programmer